# In a batch update, workflow is only retriggered on the entities where there is a change?

Tags: workflow

I was reading the following document: [Field Updates That Re-evaluate Workflow Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_field_updates_reevalute_wf.htm&type=0)

There is one point mentioned in this document:

> In a batch update, workflow is only retriggered on the entities where there is a change.

What is meant by this statement?

Answer (score 1):

Its just clarification of the non plural comment

> Salesforce re-evaluates all workflow rules on the object if the field update results in a change to the value of the field

In the presence of multiple records in the trigger SF will on trigger workflow reevaluation on those records where a WFR with reevaluation enabled actually triggered a change. **Records where the WFR evaluated to false will not be reevaluated**